# Colorbox opening just one time after form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

We have a situation where form submit results had to be shown in a Colorbox. For that we did a jQuery.post request and tried to open up the returned html in colorbox. Here is the code for that.

```
jQuery("#f1").submit(function(){
    var formData = $(this).serializeArray();
    jQuery.post("index.php", formData, function(r){
        jQuery.fn.colorbox({html:r,width:"80%",height:"80%",title:"Event Details"});
    });
        return false; // To override non-ajax submitting
    });
```

All works well but just for the first time. So when form submit happens first time it opens up in colorbox. The Second time it opens up in new page. What is probably wrong here?

Comment: As I understand it's not colorbox issue? Without colorbox line you still having problem with form default action?

Comment: Where do you see the issue in form default action?

Comment: I am just asking, if am I right other code removes jquery `submit` event and form submits with usual `POST` request. It's not clear `it opens up in new page`. Absolutely new page? Or this page refreshes?

Comment: The page opens like in case of normal form submit

Comment: It's possible, that you `unbind` submit event or just changing html markup and event not working. Your example works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/HtXb2/ Try to localize the problem.

Comment: You have not added the Ajax jQuery.post code in your case, What i doubt is there is a loss of reference of colorbox